# Как заменить скрытую ссылку?

Tags: php, javascript, html, .htaccess

Всем здрасьте. Скачал шаблон, в нем где-то в скрипте есть скрытая ссылка на адрес. Прямым поиском найти не могу. Пробовал всё. Появилась идея. Можно ли эту ссылку перекрыть другой с помощью файла .htaccess? То есть, левая ссылка выглядит так - `site1/profile/xxxxxx`, а мой домен `site`. Должно получится `site/profile/xxxxxx`. Ну или посоветуйте другой способ. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Перекрыть не получиться. Попробуйте пройдитесь поиском по файлам и БД, если она есть.

Comment: Деньги автору шаблона заплатите!

Comment: Смотрел бд, чекал все файлы через Notepad++. Ссылка зашифрована. Искал в файлах - fsockopen, curl_exec,base64_decode, base64

Comment: ссылка там вообще левая. Копирайтов никаких нет. Я бы сказал шаблон паблик, поэтому и платить некому

Comment: Если ссылка левая, то там не только она есть, но и вирусы/трояны/бэкдоры :P

Comment: это очевидно, но мне просто интересно. если нельзя найти, то можно ли её перекрыть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ссылка была зашифрована в коде JS. Код был в кодировке urlencode. Путем перевода из urlencode в ASCII-BIT я нашел ссылку.